# Replacing variable number of spaces in a line with a single comma in python

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape final voting data from a website  (https://www.bexar.org/DocumentCenter/View/22152/June-8-2019-Election-Totals-Report) to use in map-making. While I can narrow down a lot of it by just copying the data that I need (CITY OF SAN ANTONIO Mayor), the amount of spaces between the precinct (1001, 1002, etc) and the first vote total are variable depending on the amount of votes (35 spaces for a 2 digit vote count in the 1st column, 34 spaces for a 3 digit, and so on).

The issue that  I'm having is that I haven't used python in 2 years and I'm just trying to get the precinct and vote totals into Excel to get some extra data from them without having to manually input them. I was trying to just make a CSV file out of the data on the website and importing that into Excel.

I've tried to remember some of the python I've learned, and was able to replace *any* occurrence of a space with a comma, but that won't work for a CSV file as far as I know.

Here's what I've done so  far.

```
import re
filename = open("E:\Downloads\data.txt")
contents = filename.read()
print(re.sub("[ ,.]", ",", contents))
```

This gives me

```
1001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,172,,,,26,,,,,0,,,,,1
1002,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,27,,,,50,,,,,0,,,,,0
```

and so on, and not

```
1001,172,26,0,1
1002,27,50,0,0
```

which is my desired result.

Thanks so much for  the help :)

Comment: What is inside data.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
re.sub("[ ]{2,}",",", string)
```

It will replace two or more spaces with comma.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
numspaces=4
contents=contents.replace(" "*numspaces,",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use \W to match any non-word character:

```
contents = re.sub(r'\W+', ',', contents)
```

To be more accurate

```
contents = re.sub(r'(\W)\1+', r'\1', contents)
```

[Regex Test](https://regex101.com/r/eM5kV8/1)

Comment: This answer gives the output!

Answer (score 0):

This will change your agent header so you do not appear as a bot. You will hit a parse blocker on Java pages. To scrape a java page you will need to use something like Selenium. https://stanford.edu/~mgorkove/cgi-bin/rpython_tutorials/Scraping_a_Webpage_Rendered_by_Javascript_Using_Python.php

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

try:
    url = input('Enter full website address (http://, https://:> ')
    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (x11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respdata = resp.read()


except Exception as e:
    print('That is not a valid website address\nCheck the web address'
          , (e))

content = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>', str(respdata))
for contents in content:
    print(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def func(string):
        lst =string.split(",")
        result =",".join([i for i in lst if i!=""])
        return result
    a ='1001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,172,,,,26,,,,,0,,,,,1'
    b='1002,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,27,,,,50,,,,,0,,,,,0'
    print(func(a))
    #1001,172,26,0,1
```